# Can't seem to find openssl@1.1 on osx 12.3.1

Tags: swift, openssl, apple-m1

Having a mint issue trying to instal realm/SwiftLint.  New system and have installed mint and openssl@1.1 using home-brew.  Using OSX 12.3.1 on apple silicon.  Keep getting:

```
rbonner@ATH64694 ~ % mint install realm/SwiftLint
```

dyld[14284]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
Referenced from: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mint-lang/0.14.0/bin/mint
Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      mint install realm/SwiftLint

Here is my openssl install info:

```
rbonner@ATH64694 ~ % brew install openssl@1.1
```

Running `brew update --preinstall`...
Warning: openssl@1.1 1.1.1n is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.1.1n, run:
brew reinstall openssl@1.1

My openSSL is installed here:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/openssl
```

Not sure what I am missing here to have it be usable.

Thanks in advance!